# Are these the right search terms, to find all cards that have their costs reduced by Embalming Tools?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm using [Embalmer's Tools](https://scryfall.com/card/akh/227/embalmers-tools), and want to find all (monoblue) cards that have their cost reduced by it.

I have this search term [`(fo:/{[cwubrg1-9]}.*: .*(this|~) .* from your graveyard/ or fo:/{[cwubrg1-9]}.*(this|~).* from your graveyard:/) and id:u and t:creature`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28fo%3A%2F%7B%5Bcwubrg1-9%5D%7D.*%3A+.*%28this%7C%7E%29+.*+from+your+graveyard%2F+or+fo%3A%2F%7B%5Bcwubrg1-9%5D%7D.*%28this%7C%7E%29.*+from+your+graveyard%3A%2F%29+and+id%3Au+and+t%3Acreature&unique=cards&as=grid&order=edhrec), which brings back 17 cards currently.

Is this a complete search term?

Comment: You said "blue cards", which generally includes multicolored cards but in the search you have "id:u", which includes only monocolored cards and artifacts. Which of those do you want?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I'm after monoblue, but that's not really the important part in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an alternate search that finds a few more cards. It looks like the main error in yours, and this is very minor, is putting a space both before and after the `.*` clause after `(this|~)` in the first regular expression. The result is that it misses the simple phrase "Return ~ from your graveyard to the battlefield" because there is no word in between the card's name and "from".

> [`(fo:/{\d+}.*:.*(this card|~).*(in|from) your graveyard/ or fo:/{\d+}.*(this card|~).*from your graveyard.*:/) and t:creature and id:u`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28fo%3A%2F%7B%5Cd%2B%7D.*%3A.*%28this+card%7C%7E%29.*%28in%7Cfrom%29+your+graveyard%2F+or+fo%3A%2F%7B%5Cd%2B%7D.*%28this+card%7C%7E%29.*from+your+graveyard.*%3A%2F%29+and+t%3Acreature+and+id%3Au&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name)

There are a couple of refinements here. First, I searched for only generic mana costs, because those are the only ones affected by Embalmer's Tools. Second, I fixed the spacing issue I mentioned. Interestingly, if I add the option of the word "in" instead of from in the first regular expression, and remove the color restriction, this would also find cards such as [Carrionette](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCarrionette%5d), which has an activated ability with the restriction

> Activate this ability only if Carrionette is in your graveyard.

My search does find [Startled Awake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStartled%20Awake%5d) as a false positive because only one of its faces is a creature, and that face is not the one with the activated ability.